# RealVNC Server doesn't run on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vnc

RealVNC Server simply doesn't run on freshly installed `Ubuntu 22.04`. It starts well on Live Ubuntu booting from USB flash drive, when I'm installing it the same way (downloading version `7.5.1` from `realvnc.com`, then running the .deb package via Software Install). Any thoughts?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I tried to search my problem but there is no info about exactly my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg.
- `WaylandEnable=false` # Yes this line in that file.
- `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` # will KIll you session. Save everything before running this command

Taken From below link and It works on Ubuntu 22.04,

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Comment: Thank you so much!
I'll try it when will deal with it again, for sure.

Comment: Thanks you for this information, it worked 100% for me, first try!

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours of frustration. I'd tried numerous things numerous times, and this resolved it for me on a brand new 22.04 installation using RealVNC v6. I suspect it may also make v5 work again too.